# Add Identity framework to existing Database, Used Code-First approach

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, code-first, asp.net-identity-2

I build MyApplication in layered style keeping the responsibility separate from other layers, I've added separate ClassLibraries for my DAL and ModelLayer.

- **MyApplication**    (WebApp)
- **MyApplication.DBAccessLayer** (DAL) - ClassLibrary
- **MyApplication.DBModelLayer** (Entity Classes) - ClassLibrary

In my DataAccessLayer have Entity-Framework package installed, migration enabled and ModelLayer is referened in the DAL. I'm successfully able to do Automatic/Manual Migrations and maintain DB structure.

Now I want to add Identity Framework to incorporate Authentication & Authorization into my project. My question is, which layer should I add it on?

**Following are my changes to add Identity, Please have a look. I appreciate Any suggestions or correction in my approach.**

I'm new to .Net framework so please guide me if m wrong with my approach. I've tried implementing Identity Framework using ASP.MVC 5, Code-First Approach. I believe I'm half way through but while testing it, Every time I try to register user it fails in Account/Register()

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, 
                                             Email = model.Email };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, 
                                                       model.Password);
Here------> if (result.Succeeded)  <---- Here To be precise
            {
                await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, 
                                               isPersistent:false, 
                                              rememberBrowser:false);
             }
         }}
```

I've gone through different articles and learned the basics of Identity framework and how to do it. Installed following packages into DAL layer

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin 
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb
```

Moved `WebApp/Models/IdentityModel.cs` classes, which comes with the **ASP.net MVC 5** template, moved it into my Model Library and AppDbContext class into my DAL library.

IdentityModel.cs Looks like

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("MyConnectionName", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

Made by Context class extend ApplicationDbContext class defined in IdentityModel above.

```
public class Context : ApplicationDbContext
    {
        public Context() : base()
        {

        }
    }
```

Also added IdentityConfig class in `App_Start` folder, that is to be used by OWIN

```
public class IdentityConfig
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(() => new ApplicationDbContext());
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<RoleManager<AppRole>>((options, context) =>
            new RoleManager<AppRole>(
                new RoleStore<AppRole>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>())));

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Home/Login"),
        });
    }
}
```

and referenced it in `web.config` to be visible to OWIN

```
<appSettings>
    <!-- other settings -->
    <add key="owin:AppStartup" value="MyAppNamespace.IdentityConfig" />
</appSettings>
```

I've also updated my Database which added Identity Tables into my Database
i.e `AspNetRoles` `AspNetUserClaims` `AspNetLogins` `AspNetUserRoles` `AspNetUsers`

Comment: Set a break point on the line that errors. Now inspect result.Errors to see what failed. Could be your password does not match your rules, etc.

Comment: Already checked that, the result.errorMessage is `Passwords must have at least one non-letter or digit character` which I already checked that it satisfies the validation need.

Comment: That message is pretty reliable. What is your password at the debug point? Show your PasswordValidator code (from ApplicationUserManager in App_start\IdentityConfig). Or flip your `RequireNonLetterOrDigit` to false and see if it passes.

Comment: 'Asdf123' This is my password at the debug point right before `if (result.Succeeded)`
and here's PasswordValidator
`manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
            {
                RequiredLength = 6,
                RequireNonLetterOrDigit = true,
                RequireDigit = true,
                RequireLowercase = true,
                RequireUppercase = true,
            };`

Comment: Where is the non letter non digit? You need a special character like $ or change the setting. That is the expected behavior.

Comment: Opps.. My bad big time, I ignored it and providing non-letter as a numbers only and not the special characters.
apart from that if you are planning to improve you App and incorporate more features is this modeling is correct? it was actually 2nd part of my question. would appreciate your thoughts on that as well. thanks again

Comment: Stack Overflow is not for code reviews. [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) is.

Comment: Yeah, we are doing very similar based on [this](http://johnatten.com/2014/04/20/asp-net-mvc-and-identity-2-0-understanding-the-basics/#The-Heart-of-it-All---ApplicationDbContext). There are some places where Identity is tightly coupled so we were not able to remove references from the MVC project as we had hoped. Ran into [this technique](https://jinishbhardwaj.wordpress.com/2014/07/16/decoupling-asp-net-identity-2-0-from-entity-framework-in-mvc5-part-1/) but seemed like too much work for the benefits.

Comment: If the gist of your question is about combining the Identity stuff with your business stuff - then yes, lots of people doing that.